# Imagem em cima de texto com CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, css3

Galera, estou querendo gerar uma imagem, que assim que a pessoa descer o scroll, a imagem suba mais rápida do que o texto por traz.
Um exemplo disso é o elemento " C " nesse site no meio da página.

http://www.cmaise.com.br/

Criei um jsfiddle para tentar elaborar mais não consegui. https://jsfiddle.net/0uzpwbgo/

Gostaria de uma ajuda aos mais entendedores, obrigado.

Comment: Marquei a tua pergunta como duplicada de outra pois refere-se à mesma técnica. Se achares errado diz claro. Até breve.

Comment: Legal, não conhecia, voce poderia me ajudar com o meu código?